# Is there a way to add the Content Type title inside our custom list validation settings' Formual

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, list, development, validation

I have a cusotm list inside our sharepoint team site, and inside the list Validation setting i define the following formula:-

```
=IF(Status="Invoiced",IF([Invoiced Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)=IF(Status="Delivered",IF([Delivered Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

the formula will check if the date fields are entered based on the current status. Our cusotm list have 3 content types, and for all content types they have the above fields (status, Delivered Date & Invoiced Date). but now i need to add an extra validation , as follow:-

1. if content type = "Personal Form".
2. and status = "In Progress".
3. to force user to enter a field named "Date of Birth".

now the "Date of Birth" field will only be inside a single content type named "Personal Form", but seems inside the Validation list's Inset Column select menu, there is not any option to select the content type:-
[image]

So can anyone advice how i can define my extra validation formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite PreSaveAction function on list forms to validate the entered data before saving the data.

In the **NewForm.aspx**, we need check the ContentTypeID in the URL to know which the content type is used.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function GetParameterValues(param) {  
    var url = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');  
    for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {  
        var urlparam = url[i].split('=');  
        if (urlparam[0] == param) {  
            return urlparam[1];  
        }  
    }  
}

function PreSaveItem(){
    var result = true;
    //check the content type
    var contentTypeId = GetParameterValues('ContentTypeId');
    //check field values
    var invoicedDate = $('input[title="Invoiced Date"]').val();
    var deliveredDate = $('input[title="Delivered Date"]').val();
    // status is a drop down list
    var status=$("select[title='Status'] option:selected").text();
    if(status == "Invoiced" && invoicedDate == ""){
        alert("please enter Invoiced Date");
        result = false;
    }
    if(status == "Delivered" && deliveredDate == ""){
        alert("please enter Delivered Date");
        result = false;
    }
    if(contentTypeId == "0x01005FBBC90E32AA63449CAC5DE5819EBF2300839177067F7AC647BDDFBB0D03834E7A"){
        var dateOfBirth = $('input[title="Date of Birth"]').val();      
        if(status== "In Progress" && dateOfBirth == ""){
            alert("please enter Date of Birth");
            result = false;
        }   
    }
    return result;
}
</script>
```

In the **EditForm.aspx**, check the Content Type choice in the form.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function PreSaveItem(){
    var result = true;
    //check the content type
    var contentType=$("select[title='Content Type'] option:selected").text();
    //check field values
    var invoicedDate = $('input[title="Invoiced Date"]').val();
    var deliveredDate = $('input[title="Delivered Date"]').val();
    // status is a drop down list
    var status=$("select[title='Status'] option:selected").text();
    if(status == "Invoiced" && invoicedDate == ""){
        alert("please enter Invoiced Date");
        result = false;
    }
    if(status == "Delivered" && deliveredDate == ""){
        alert("please enter Delivered Date");
        result = false;
    }
    if(contentType == "cusItem"){ //if the content type of the current item is “cusItem”
        var dateOfBirth = $('input[title="Date of Birth"]').val();  
        if(status== "In Progress" && dateOfBirth == ""){
            alert("please enter Date of Birth");
            result = false;
        }   
    }
    return result;
}
</script>
```

**Note**:

Change `"0x01005FBBC90E32AA63449CAC5DE5819EBF2300839177067F7AC647BDDFBB0D03834E7A"` to your conten type ID. And change the `"cusItem"` to your content type name "Personal Form".

You can find the content type ID from the URL of the NewForm.aspx when creating item using this content type.

A demo about how to use PreSaveAction function:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31330.sharepoint-using-presaveaction-function-on-custom-list-forms.aspx