# Apply the list validation to only certain content types

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, content-type, validation, list-validation

I have the following formula inside the list validation:

```
=IF(Status="Invoiced",IF([Customer Invoiced Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)=IF(Status="Commission Paid",IF([Commission Paid Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)=IF(Status="Delivered",IF([Order Delivered Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

and I have 3 content types for the list:

1. Project
2. Sales
3. Task

Where I want to apply the formula only if content type != Task? Can anyone advice?

Comment: Are the fields used in validation formula added to all content types?

Comment: Are you using modern experience for list forms or classic experience??

Comment: @GaneshSanap i am using classic

Comment: If you are using classic experience then it can be easily achieved using client side scripting (javascript) by overriding `PreSaveAction()` function - check 1st link in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the "Content Type" in list validation formulas.

So, there is no way to add the conditional formula based on the current content type selected on list form.

If you are using classic experience, you can override the `PreSaveAction()` function on list forms to validate the entered data before saving the data.

For more information on using `PreSaveAction()`, check this: [Is there a way to add the Content Type title inside our custom list validation settings' Formual](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/250541/is-there-a-way-to-add-the-content-type-title-inside-our-custom-list-validation-s)

**Similar questions**:

1. [List Item Validation With The Content Type Field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/283698/list-item-validation-with-the-content-type-field)
2. [Use "Content Type" in list or column validation](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/133b04f5-c20b-411e-97b8-7dcc169e9e54/use-quotcontent-typequot-in-list-or-column-validation)

---

**Update from comments**:

If you want to **disable** the validation when `ItemNumber` column contains **-Task-**, use below formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("-Task-", [ItemNumber])), <Your-Original-Formula>, TRUE)
```

The later validation in above formula will trigger when `ItemNumber` column does not contain **-Task-**.

Comment: ok fine .. in this case i have  field called ItemNumber.. and if the Item number does not contain "-Task-" i want to disable the validation is this possible?

Comment: Check updated answer. you can **disable** the validation if Item number **does not** contain "-Task-".

Comment: actually if the itemnumber contain -Task- to disable the validation..

Comment: That's what I thought earlier so highlighted the text in above comment :D . Check updated formula, it should work for you now.